# HTML <title> tag appearing on page

Tags: html, css, title

I am working on a webpage right now and have JUST started working on the content/css.  I've built many webpages in the past and am using two different CSS files (reset.css and styles.css) to style the pages that I will be creating.

However, when I created this most recent page, the `<title>` tag is displaying in the webpage when I test it.  Is there any way I can get around this?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>HOME _ JWD</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-logo"></div>
            <div class="header-navbar">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**RESET CSS**
    html {
        font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    }

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
* {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**STYLES CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #666666;
    display: block;
    line-height: 75px;
}
.header-logo {
    background-image: url(../images/logo_fullwidth.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 75px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .header-logo {
    background-image:url(../images/logo_mobile.png)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like some validation of the page code is needed.

Comment: It's 100% your reset.css

Comment: Blindly setting every element to block-level is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

```
* { display: block; }

<head>
  <title>HOME _ JWD</title>
</head>
```

Your css implicitly contains this too:

```
head, title { display: block; }
```

Do you see what you did? :)
If you really want to blockify everything, you could fix it by writing:

```
body * { display: block; }
```

Comment: That was definitely it...I feel like a doof now haha.  Thanks!  Couldn't figure out for the life of me what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Title tags by default are `display: none;`

By adding a selector for everything, `*`, to set them to `block` you've inadvertently asked the browser to display it. Either select the title tag and set it back to `none` or change your existing selector to be more specific.

However, setting everything to block is not a good idea. There are plenty of tags, such as spans, which you likely would not like to be block elements during later development. As such I would go with making the existing selector more specific.

Answer (score 1):

This is your culprit

```
* {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

title is part of * (everything)

You may want to be more specific with what displays as a block

I suspect you only need things inside the body tag to display as such

```
body * {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Furthermore, I would like to point out that `<div>` elements do display as blocks by default so you don't need to explicitly declare the `display:block` property unless you want to override a previously declared display property